# 'unfortunately, app has stopped' Android/Cordova app

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

I just set  up an Android/Cordova 2.0.0 app with pretty nothing in it except the simple index page from the Cordova "getting started" guide.
But I am getting "unfortunately, app has stopped instantly when I run the project in the 4.0.3 simulator. I can run older projects I've done with no problem.

Here is the logCat content:

```
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10040 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:597)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:365)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager.execute(NetworkManager.java:124)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:218)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:207)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:600)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-21 09:13:30.881: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my androidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.active.myApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".myAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my activity file:

```
package com.active.myApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class myAppActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I hadn't added my permissions yet when I posted and then wehen I forgot this one. Thanks!

Comment: I did add this line to the manifest but on running the command cordova run android the manifest file gets reset with the old commands

Answer (score 6):

You need to give your app all privileges, that your cordova setup needs. AFAIK this includes at least the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` privilege now posing the problem.

Try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

inside your `<manifest>` element in your AndroidManifest.xml and work from there.

Comment: Our app crashed on Galaxy S3, but works on S4, S5 etc. Adding permission for android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE made it work on the S3. Strange.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone new to Cordova, run:

`~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat`

Clear the screen (command-k in Terminal.app on Mac OS X) then run your app from a separate console:

`cordova run android`

When your app crashes, look at the logcat output.  In my case, there was mention of OpenGL so I ran:

`~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd`

Then edited my emulator and checked `Use Host GPU` and was able to run it after that.  I was lucky that it was something this simple, YMMV.